# TypeError: clean() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, spacy

I am using python to do sentiment analysis on Colab Notebook.
This is my code using Cleantext and spaCy.

```
def prep(text):
    cleaned = clean(text, fix_unicode=True, to_ascii=True, lower=False, no_line_breaks=True, no_urls=True,
                    no_emails=True, no_phone_numbers=False, no_numbers=False, no_digits=True, no_currency_symbols=True, 
                    no_punct=True, replace_with_url="URL_ADDRESS", replace_with_email="EMAIL_ADDRESS",
                    replace_with_phone_number="<PHONE>", replace_with_number="<NUMBER>",
                    replace_with_digit="INTEGER", replace_with_currency_symbol="CUR", lang="en")
    doc = nlp(cleaned)
    processed =' '.join([token.lemma_ if str(token) not in ['Our','our','We','we','us'] else str(token) for token in doc])
    return processed
```

Using this function to preprocess data works fine on local jupyter notebook but on Colab, I got `TypeError: clean() got an unexpected keyword argument` How can I fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Please show the full Error

Comment: where did you define your clean() function? It says that you used wrong argument for clean() function, just find typo errors,...

Comment: Check that the version you are using is the same that you are using for the documentation reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your package.

```
pip install clean-text[gpl]==0.4.0
```

Comment: this is not working for me